# Scraping a website whose encoding is iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8: how do I store the correct unicode in my database?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape a website using Python that is full of horrible problems, one being the wrong encoding at the top:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

This is wrong because the page is full of occurrences like the following:

`Nellâ€™ambito`

instead of

`Nell'ambito` (please notice `â€™` replaces `'`)

If I understand correctly, this is happening because utf-8 bytes (probably the database encoding) are interpreted as iso-8859-1 bytes (forced by the charset in the meta tag).
I found some initial explanation at this link http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

I am using BeautifulSoup to navigate the page, Google App Engine's urlfetch to make requests, however all I need is to understand what is the correct way to store in my database a string that fixes `â€™` by encoding the string to `'`.

Comment: Do you mean that when you actually visit the page you see the wrong characters, or that you end up with the wrong characters when you display the data in your own application or view it in the database? How are you scraping it now? How are you decoding and re-encoding the characters? Are you sure the page is valid UTF-8 even though it claims not to be?

Comment: Yes, the page displays the wrong characters. When I scrape the page, it receives exactly what there's on the page. BeautifulSoup converts everything to utf-8, apart from that I'm not explicitly encoding and decoding characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am using BeautifulSoup to navigate the page, Google App Engine's urlfetch to make requests

Are you feeding the encoding from the `Content-Type` HTTP header into BeautifulSoup?

If an HTML page has both a Content-Type header and a meta tag, the header should ‘win’, so if you're only taking the meta tag you may get the wrong encoding.

Otherwise, you could either feed the fixed encoding `'utf-8'` into Beautiful, or fix up each string indvidually.

Annoying note: it's not actually ISO-8859-1. When web pages *say* ISO-8859-1, browsers actually take it to mean Windows code page 1252, which is similar to 8859-1 but not the same. The `€` would seem to indicate cp1252 because it's not present in 8859-1.

```
u'Nellâ€™ambito'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
```

If the content is encoded inconsistently with some UTF-8 and some cp1252 on the same page (typically due to poor database content handling), this would be the only way to recover it, catching `UnicodeError` and returning the original string when it wouldn't transcode.

Comment: I am feeding this to BeautifulSoup: BeautifulSoup(r.content, from_encoding='utf-8') - is that wrong?


The accept-charset header is Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Comment: Your solution works, except for some reason, it's `'latin1'` instead of `'cp1252'`.

Comment: The charset you want is the one from the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=...` response header, from `headers` on the urlfetch response object. Except that for `text/html`, `iso-8859-1` is misleading, as above. Odd: `latin1` is a synonym for `iso-8859-1`, and that encoding doesn't have a euro sign in, so the given example should fail.

Comment: in scala which I prefer for most tasks these days you can use the Charset from nio and the String function via new String. Scala is as compact as python but will easily let you leverage threads alongside processes.