# Python + BeautifulSoup + Encode/Decode a web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, decode, encode

Here are the facts :

I want to scrape a particular text from a web page. This text is a price : 25€.
I know from the source code that the web page is encoded in iso-8859-15.

Right now I am using the windows cmd, but ultimately the code would be on a server.

The ultimate goal is to record only the figure in a database, I don't care about the € symbol. That's why I only care about the iso-8859-15 DECODING, but not of any ENCODING ? I want my code to encode nothing if it can not encode... The command I am looking for (in my dreams) is the following : "print if you can, and if you can not, print nothing".

As of today, my code is the following :

```
import codecs
import sys
streamWriter = codecs.lookup('iso-8859-15')[-1]
sys.stdout = streamWriter(sys.stdout)
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "Some url"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
  print link.contents[0].text
```

But I am facing several erros with special symbols, like the €.

I found a beginning of a solution, which could be to implement a new method called "myprint", which basically would do what I want, i.e. instead of exiting the code with an error, would continue with a printed'' (nothing) instead. But I was not able to find/do/write much more, any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514203/scraping-a-website-whose-encoding-is-iso-8859-1-instead-of-utf-8-how-do-i-store

Answer (score 0):

To implement the exact function you specify,

```
def myprint(text):
    try: print text
    except: print ''
```

However, you can likely do better than that.

`BeautifulSoup` gives you unicode; in particular, it handles the decoding for you, if the page's headers correctly describe it.  You say you don't care about encoding -- and yet, you do, if you want to `print` stuff to standard output, and indeed you're trying to do that.  If BS gets the encoding wrong but you know the right one, just use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, from_encoding="iso-8859-15")
```

and take the now-correct supplied unicode from `soup`.  (If you do in fact need to encode, e.g for printing, please edit your Q accordingly!)